# Getting a Webpack error when trying to run yarn run build-assets

Tags: django, vue.js, yarnpkg

I'm trying to create a web app using Django for backend and Vue.js for frontend, and to make that happen I had to use the module bundler "webpack", but after I made all the necessary configurations and run the Django server it gives me this error.

> OSError at / Error reading project_path\webpack-stats.json. Are you sure webpack has generated the file and the path is correct?

I found out that the **webpack-stats.json** wasn't generated, so I made some research of how to generate a **webpack-stats.json** file, after I found that the command

```
yarn run build-assets
```

is supposed to generate that file automatically. but when I run it, it gives the following error

> An unexpected error occurred: "Command \"build-assets\" not found."

Is there any other solution so I can generate **webpack-stats.json** file?

Comment: Can you generate it yourself by doing: `webpack --profile --json > webpack-stats.json`

Answer (score 2):

Try to install the earlier version of the packages such as  **django-webpack-loader==0.6.0** and **webpack-bundle-tracker@0.2.1**. Then run **yarn serve** or **npm run serve** for npm users to create the **webpack-stats.json** on the frontend directory.

Packages with version, django-webpack-loader==0.7.0, and webpack-bundle-tracker@1.0.0-alpha.1 cannot automatically generate  webpack-stats.json and will likely to cause OSError.

For projects using Django==3.0.6 and @vue/cli 4.3.1.